# #select_all gives different contents of BYTEA fields than a simple ActiveRecord model-based query does

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I'm using Rails 5.1.7 to extract data from one database and insert into another. Examine the following output from the Rails console:

```
irb(main):098:0> arel = Upload.order('id desc').limit(1).select('content')
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Upload id: nil, content: "PK\\003\\004\\024\\000\\010\\010\\010\\00047\\363V\\000\\000\\...">]>
irb(main):099:0> puts arel.first.content[0..10]
PK\003\004\
=> nil
irb(main):100:0> puts Upload.connection.select_all(arel.to_sql).first['content'][0..10]
\x504b5c303
=> nil
irb(main):101:0> puts Upload.count
2943
=> nil
irb(main):102:0> puts arel.first.content.encoding
ASCII-8BIT
=> nil
irb(main):103:0> puts Upload.connection.select_all(arel.to_sql).first['content'].encoding
UTF-8
=> nil
```

Note that the aRel gives me an ASCII-8BIT string while the select_all gives me a UTF-8 string and that the strings look nothing alike. The content happens to be a PKZipped file, but when I insert the UTF-8 version into a database and later try to retrieve it and process it as a PKZIP archive, it is not recognized as such (but the ASCII-8BIT encoded string processes just fine). Looking at the strings, this is not surprising as they look nothing alike.

I've not been able to find a way to convert/encode the UTF-8 string so that I get a string identical to the ASCII-8BIT string. Before you suggest it, I of course tried ".encode('ASCII-8BIT')" and it did not work in that the contents of the string looked the same as before changing the encoding even though the encoding was now ASCII-8BIT.

Because I'm extracting the data from a second database and copying it to my main database, I'm restricted to using connection-based commands such as #select_all instead of the simple model-based aRel queries.

Answer (score 0):

The `select_all` is returning you the data (for whatever reason) encoded in hex.

> \x504b5c303

- \x denotes that this is in hexadecimal
- 50 in hex is P in ascii
- 4b in hex is K in ascii
- 5c in hex is backslash in ascii and so on.

There are multiple ways to convert between them. Here is one example:

```rb
["504b5c303"].pack('H*') #=> "PK\\00"
```

Comment: Well, your idea worked for that one record, but there were records in other formats, such as "PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\b\b\b\x00w", which before applying #pack looked like ""PK\\003\\004\\" using #select_all, and which therefore did not behave well with #pack.